# Dynamically link to Google Maps route planner and always use car as preferred form of transport

Tags: google-maps

I have some addresses and want to create links to the Google Maps route planner. You can link to it by simply visiting `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/<address 1>/<address 2>/`, e.g. https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Thompson+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA/Wooster+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA/

My problem here is, that for short distances, Google returns walking as the preferred form of transport (as in my link above). Which is good in terms of environment protection and keeping yourself healthy, but I definitely need the route with a car. How can I modify the link to always use car?

When visiting the link above, Google redirects to [another URI](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Thompson+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA/Wooster+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA/@40.7251221,-74.0035437,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2598e06b5e4b5:0x3ccb22452b1c1c03!2m2!1d-74.0016295!2d40.7260881!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2598b919fe461:0x4c1d8fabc198ea46!2m2!1d-74.0011735!2d40.7241562) with a lot of parameters. When I manually select car as form of transportation, the URI [gets altered slightly into a new one](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Thompson+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA/Wooster+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA/@40.7251262,-74.0042194,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2598e06b5e4b5:0x3ccb22452b1c1c03!2m2!1d-74.0016295!2d40.7260881!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2598b919fe461:0x4c1d8fabc198ea46!2m2!1d-74.0011735!2d40.7241562!3e0): `!3e0` gets added. But adding `!3e0` or `data=!3e0` to my link from above (https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Thompson+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA/Wooster+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA/data=!3e0) doesn't change anything. I also tried adding some of the other added parameters, but either they don't change anything or they contain the info about Thompson St. and Wooster St., so changing the readable parameters (`<address 1/2>`) doesn't work again.

Comment: @Downvoter: I'd really like to know why this question gets downvoted without any comment 8 months after posting it.

Comment: Wow, another downvote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first: 
None of the URL-parameters are documented, so the result is not guaranteed to be stable.

A unofficial list for parameters for the old google-maps may be found at http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

Many of these parameters still work when you'll be redirected to the new google-maps.

According to that list the needed parameters are:

- `f`
  (mode) set it to `d`
- `saddr`
  start-address
- `daddr`
  destination-address
- `dirflg`
  set it to `d`

result:

[`https://www.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=Thompson+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA&daddr=Wooster+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA&dirflg=d`](https://www.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=Thompson+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA&daddr=Wooster+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA&dirflg=d)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I know that none of these parameters are documented anywhere and may disappear, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 13):

There is an official documentation now: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

In your case the link would be:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Thompson+St,+New+York,+NY,+USA&travelmode=driving`